# UnknkownHostException

Tags: java, deployment, glassfish

Please help;

Am trying to deploy a web application.
The build is returning successful,and am not getting any errors on the sever.log
however am getting a http 503 error:the requested service() is not currently available
and also my 
Java DB Database Process has this message
Warning: UnknkownHostException: intracare: intracare.
Could not listen on port 1527 on host localhost.

am using glassfish v3 prelude

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you already have another application (perhaps another JavaDB instance?) listening on port 1527 - that could explain the "could not listen" message. Use `netstat` to check.

Answer (score 1):

I think that UnknownHostException is related that **intracare** can't be resolved to an IP.

I would:

1. Ping that host.
2. Check *C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts* or */etc/hosts* files.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Check the DNS settings on the host.  Your short names do not resolve correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Mayby string you are typing as a host name is wrong? Maybe it is firewall problem?